# Getting error of "entity_share_client.commands"

Tags: 8, updating

While trying to update Drupal core I was facing issue with error

```
- drupal/entity_share 1.x-dev requires drupal/jsonapi >=1.0.0 <2.0.0
```

But updating version of drupal/entity_share to latest version resolve this issue. Now while trying to update database it gives an error saying

*ERROR: The service "drush.command.services" has a dependency on a non-existent service "entity_share_client.commands".*

In composer.json drupal/entity_share version is "^2.0" and Drupal version is updated to 8.7.6. Also, I m using JSON API module and Entity share module too. Not getting any solution to resolve "entity_share_client.commands" error. Any suggestion?

Comment: Make sure that the entity_share module is enabled.

Comment: @Jdrupal Yes its enable.